# Doing Overhaul of Codebase: .NET or Delphi backend?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, delphi, remobjects

I have little experience in C#.NET, but have years in Delphi.  Any Delphi + .NET people out there that can provide me some guidance?

Here's the scoop:

I am going to be in charge of a overhaul of the codebase (200,000 lines+). We're going to be creating a full n-tier architecture, with the front end being Silverlight. We chose Silverlight as the front end because it can be deployed in a browser as well as an application with minimal effort, from my research.

I have not been able to find a clear comparison between Remobjects SDK and WCF. The few threads I encountered mention the issues with WCF, such as response times, large overhead, and [somewhat snotty responses from MS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ed3ff5d6-62e7-481f-84c0-c28a5a7240b8/).

This question is more for the backend. Our current codebase is in Delphi. Is it worth keeping the backend in Delphi, if at all possible?  The debate is between using WCF if moving to .NET, or using Remobjects SDK (.NET and Delphi flavours simultaneously) if sticking with Delphi.

Pros of Delphi backend + Silverlight frontend:

- Existing codebase: Less time during migration
- Existing Knowledge: Developers familiar with our codebase are already familiar with Delphi
- Easy Deployment: The single exe/dll deployment is difficult to ignore!
- Cadence: The Remobjects SDK has been solid for years

Cons of Delphi Remobjects SDK backend + Silverlight + Remobjects SDK frontend:

- Technology: Is it even possible for Remobjects .NET to communicate with Remobjects Delphi with Session functionality?
- Knowledge: Other that our few developers, the knowledge of delphi is very thin in our city area.
- Project code re-use: We would need to re-develop classes in C# as well as Delphi for use in Silverlight.
- Cost: Additional cost in licensing
- Future: hard to say when Delphi will collapse

Now for the WCF .NET..
Pros of WCF .NET backend + Silverlight frontend:

- Project code re-use: A class can be used in both the backend and frontend
- Technology: Its already proven
- Knowledge: Our city area loves .NET, so there is lots of talent available to hire.
- Future: Everyone knows that MS is making tons of money off .NET and VS 2010. This adds some stability to the .NET architecture.

Cons of WCF .NET backend + Silverlight frontend:

- Existing Codebase: Our entire codebase would need to be redone, aside from class structure references.
- Deployment: I myself have not deployed a WCF application, but I know its more complicated than Delphi.
- Cadence: Microsoft is notorious for changing the game as soon as the industry settles. Happened to COM, when will it for .NET?

What would be the ideal situation?  After writing this all out, its looking like C# backend is the winner, due to the lower costs and higher chance of a stable future. Whichever backend we use now will be the method of choice for all projects in the future.

- What are your experiences with implementing your WCF n-tier application?
- Are there clear any clear and concise books / articles that outline WCF's usage, and best practices when designing your application?
- Is there a better solution than WCF in this situation?

  Sound off your thoughts!

Comment: This is not the kind of question that belongs on Stackoverflow. I expect it will be migrated to programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: You can program in Delphi against the .Net framework, can't you?

Comment: @Warren: Is there a way for me to do it?
@Will: There is Delphi Prism, but it is not an official Delphi Product. It is from a 3rd party.
@tofutim: Winnipeg. The conferences here are full of active .NET developers, with a handful of java, c++, or other languages. The last conference I went to (Winnipeg Code Camp) was 95% .NET, 3 Java, and 2% ruby + .NET something (for behavioral testing.. yeah.)

Comment: @Warren P - please note that "What language" questions are usually off topic for Programmers - we even have entry in our [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) about them.

Comment: Umm... what? Closed as Off Topic? I voted to migrate to Programmers. Just about all the votes were to migrate to Programmers. This is certainly not off topic for PSE. It's not a "what language" question; it's a well-thought-out question looking for advice about infrastructure that just happens to be about choosing between two different frameworks.

Comment: If this question was simpler (by about 10x less lines, and did not even suggest a complete rewrite and ask in what language) and instead asked an answerable question about using Delphi back-ends with Silverlight front-ends I would vote to reopen.

Comment: Fair enough. I am aware of the sensitive nature of coding a language, which is why I tried to phrase the question around communication infrastructure compatibility ended not the language itself (doesn't matter much to me, we just have to consider the learning of a new language)

Comment: I'll recreate the question on programmers.stackexchange, except only focusing on the communication infrastructures tomorrow morning!

Comment: thread has been closed, so i cannot ANSWER, nut just for the record, you can use RemObjects SDK between .NET and Delphi, and the communication will work seamlessly, yes.Feel free to bring this discussion to http://connect.remobjects.com, if you have further questions.

Answer (score 3):

Joel on Software has a pretty good article about rewriting from scratch (http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html).  I'm not sure if that completely applies to your situation, but the gist of his article is don't rewrite, ever.  You have years of work and bug fixes already in that code, and rewriting it in another language simply won't be able to cover all of those fixes.  My recommendation would be to find a good way to interface your Delphi back-end with the new Silverlight front-end. That being said, I've never done any interfacing with Delphi, so you're on your own from there.